# Conjugacy class of $(12\cdots n)$ in $S_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups

> Claim: in $S_n$, the conjugacy class of $(12\cdots n)$ is of cardinality  $(n-1)!$.

I'm not sure how to prove this. Call this permutation $\gamma$. If $\alpha$ is conjugate to $\gamma$ then there exists $\beta$ such that:

$$\alpha = \beta \gamma \beta^{-1} = (\beta(1) \beta(2) \cdots \beta(n))$$

I guess I have to count how many possibilities are there for $\beta$, and this I'm not sure how to do.

Hint or answer much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument shows the conjugates of $\gamma$ are precisely
the $n$-cycles $(a_1\,a_2\,\ldots\, a_n)$. Each $n$-cycle
can be uniquely written with $a_1=1$ etc.

Comment: $a_1 = 1$ and the rest arbitrary, leaving us with $(n-1)\times(n-2)\times \cdots \times 1 = (n-1)!$ choices?

Comment: @Cauchy yes $\phantom{}$

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your quick response!